# How to append extra rows into a table, neither at end, nor at the beginning? - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table like like;

```
<table id="mytable">
  <tr><td><input name="field1" type="text"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input name="field2" type="text"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input name="field3[]" type="text"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input name="field4" type="text"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input id="trigger" name="mybuttom" type="button" value="clickme"></td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to add extra `<tr><td><input name="field3[]" type="text"></td></tr>` rows to this table, so I used this method;

```
var target = $('#mytable');
$('#trigger').click(function() {
  $('<tr><td><input name="field3[]" type="text"></td></tr>').appendTo(target);
});
```

This adds fields to the end of the table. But I want them to be appended in between static `field3[]` and `field4`. How can I do this?

Comment: [insert after](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) combined with [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) - eg `$('<tr><td><input name="field3[]" type="text"></td></tr>').insertAfter(target.children('tr').eq(2))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)

```
var target = $('#mytable');
$('#trigger').click(function() {
  $('<tr><td><input name="field3[]" type="text"></td></tr>').insertBefore(target.find('tr:has(input[name="field4"])'));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u3KNU/)

---

Another way is to use [before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

```
jQuery(function(){
    var target = $('#mytable');
    $('#trigger').click(function() {
        target.find('tr:has(input[name="field4"])').before('<tr><td><input name="field3[]" type="text"></td></tr>')
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LpmRB/)